# My first app can't inflate xml file error

Tags: android, android-layout

My first Android app is according "[Building a Simple User Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)". But when I run it on my device, it gave me out errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(30660): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class ViewText

E/AndroidRuntime(30660):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30660): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class ViewText
```

But, when I look into  the loaded xml, it doesn't have any TextView element in my layout file. my layout file is all as following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              >
  <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/edit_message"
            />
  <Button android:id="@+id/send_button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="@string/button_send"
          android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am confused, what's the problem? Thanks your help.

Comment: Share your Activity code.

Comment: And full error message of logcat please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all add the hint to your XML and strings... if you follow the tutorial

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

second of all make sure that those @string/... exist in your res/values/strings if not then add them

```
 <string name="edit_message"></string>
```

try this and if it doesnt work we'll see whats wrong.

Comment: I don't know why, Today I just uninstall the project and remove app from recent task bar, and reinstall it to device, it runs well. I am not change any code. thank you all the same.